# How to configure logging via log4net in an UWP App

Tags: c#, logging, uwp, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have an UWP app that uses some of my libraries.
Such libraries use log4net for logging purpose, and are shared across a number of projects, not only UWP.

I'd like to configure log4net via the usual confi section in the XML config file, but I cannot find a way to do this in an UWP project, since there isn't an app.config file.

Where should I put the following section?

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log\mylog.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="2000KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complete *pfx* answer, if you are using netStandard, you will have to use `Configure` overloads with an additional parameter `log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository`.

I haven't been able to use the `ConsoleAppender` and switch to the `DebugAppender`.

You cannot use relative path in UWP with `RollingFileAppender` since log4net will not have permission to create file in the install location of your application. I think it could work with a full path but I have seen some permissions issues (you should activate debug mode of log4net for this).

Finally, I also made a **Custom Appender** which writes file in the **Local Storage** of your application. Here is the code which should be enhanced for production use.

```
namespace AppWithLog4net
{
    public class LocalStorageFileAppender : log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender
    {

        private Stream m_stream;

        public LocalStorageFileAppender() : base() {  }

        protected override void PrepareWriter()
        {
            IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> task = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.CreateFileAsync("localStorage.log", 
                                                                            Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            m_stream = file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().Result;

            QuietWriter = new log4net.Util.QuietTextWriter(new StreamWriter(m_stream, Encoding.UTF8), ErrorHandler);
            WriteHeader();
        }

        protected override void Reset()
        {
            m_stream.Dispose();
            m_stream = null;
            base.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

With the following config file:

```
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="LocalStorageFile" type="AppWithLog4net.LocalStorageFileAppender, AppWithLog4net">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="LocalStorageFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Great answer. Only thing I would say is that you probably don't want logs going to `ApplicationData.LocalFolder` as it is _"[backed up to the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder)"_.  Perhaps `ApplicationData.LocalCacheFolder` or `TemporaryFolder`?

Comment: Hello MickyD, thanks for your comment. I have updated the response since I also think it should not be uploaded to the cloud by default.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no `App.config` file, you are going to have to configure `Log4net` programmatically.

You can store the settings in a local file (or embedded resource) and read these at application startup; reference: [Create and read a local file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

`Log4net`'s [`XmlConfigurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator.htm) class can accept these settings as a `Stream`, `FileInfo` or `XmlElement` via one of its `Configure` overloads.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(XmlElement config);
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(Stream config);
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(FileInfo config);
```

Comment: Doesn't Log4Net support a custom Log4Net.config file?

Comment: @DavidPrice Yet, but you must let Log4net know where to find this file - one way is via settings in the `app.config` file. Since this question is about an UWP app, this isn't possible as UWP has no concept of an `app.config` file. My answer shows how to reference such a custom config file via code.